# How to return a value to a function while in background process subfunction in swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, background-process

I first tried this solution to return a bool in the spot I want to return it. However, due to the parse.com function saveInBackgroundWithBlock() being a void return function, I got the error "Unexpected non-void return value in void function".

```
func saveObjectToParse(gameLocal: Game) -> Bool {
        let game = PFObject(className:"Game")
        game["sport"] = gameLocal.sport.rawValue
        var saved = false
        game.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                print("Object has been saved.")
                saved = true
                return saved
            } else {
                print("parse error")
                return saved
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I tried moving the return statements out of the subfunction like this:

```
func saveObjectToParse(gameLocal: Game) -> Bool {
        let game = PFObject(className:"Game")
        game["sport"] = gameLocal.sport.rawValue
        var saved = false
        game.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                print("Object has been saved.")
                saved = true
            } else {
                print("parse error")
            }
        }
        return saved
    }
```

However, this returns saved before the saveInBackgroundWithBlock() block executes because it is a background process. Therefore, saved will never be true, even when it is intended to be. I have tried adding a boolean flag called done and tried waiting with a while(!done) loop, but this freezes the program on the loop and the background process never executes. How can I fix these problems?

Comment: Possibilities include having whatever calls `saveObjectToParse` pass in blocks to execute for success or failure cases or reacting to a notification when the save completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with restructuring not needing a bool returned, but if you really, *really* need this set up, you could save your object **synchronously** (so your code will wait) like so,

```
do {
        try game.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: I went with changing saveObjectToParse() to a void return function and moving the code executed based on the return value of the bool into the function itself. Thank you!

Comment: Synchronous saves should *really, really* **not** be recommended. The OP just wants to create a simple wrapper function around a Parse save function. This is normal and can be easily achieved using completion blocks in swift

Answer (score 1):

Returning a value from a function but from another function doesn't make architectural sense. Nor is it possible.

You either will need to change your implementation and make both methods independent or think of using a semaphore.

http://www.g8production.com/post/76942348764/wait-for-blocks-execution-using-a-dispatch

Comment: Yes, I was expecting the answer to be closer to the second code block. I just was not sure how to ensure the other function had completed before returning saved in the larger function. The while loop tactic did not work, and I've never done anything asynchronous before.

Comment: I think you have missed the OP's intentions. It makes perfect architectural sense to propagate the completion of asynchronous operations when creating wrapper utilities

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do (create a helper function to wrap the Parse save function) makes perfect sense and can be easily accomplished.

You do not need to use semaphores and you certainly don't want to perform the operation synchronously. Instead, use a *completion hander* to let you know when the save has completed. [For more information on completion handlers see this link](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/)

```
func saveObjectToParse(gameLocal: Game, completion: (gameSaved: Bool) -> Void) {
    let game = PFObject(className:"Game")
    game["sport"] = gameLocal.sport.rawValue
    game.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // Set the completion handler to be result of the Parse save operation
        completion(gameSaved: success)
    }
}
```

You may then call this function like so

```
saveObjectToParse(someGameObject) { (gameSaved: Bool) in
    if gameSaved {
        print("The game has been saved.")
    } else {
        print("Error while saving the game")
    }
}
```

Using this technique, you could similarly propagate the entire callback of `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` through your function so you could inspect errors when they occur.

Edit: It looks like you may also be using your own custom class to represent the `Game` object. I would recommend looking into subclassing `PFObject` so you can easily and directly model your Parse classes. [More details in the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclassing-pfobject)